# How to add top margin on first item in the ListView?

Tags: android, listview, margins

This is a pretty simple question. I would like to add a top margin to the first item in my ListView. Is that possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

just add `topPadding` and `android:clipToPadding="false"` to ListView